# JpaRepository - How to query joined table?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables that needs to be joined together.

Below is my Model class

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="storetypecode")
public class StoreTypeCode implements IModel {

  @Id
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name="isenabled", nullable = false)
  private boolean isEnabled = false;

  @Column(name="displaysort", nullable = false)
  private Integer displaySort = 999;

  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "storeTypeCode")
  private Set<StoreTypeCodeTranslation> storeTypeCodeTranslationList = new HashSet<>();

  public StoreTypeCode(){
    // Do nothing
  }
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="storetypecodetranslation")
public class StoreTypeCodeTranslation implements IModel {

  @Id
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "type1")
  private String type1;

  @Column(name = "type2")
  private String type2;

  @Column(name = "lang", nullable = false)
  private String lang="en";

  @Column(name="isdefault", nullable = false)
  private boolean isDefault=false;

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  @ToString.Exclude
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @JoinColumn(name = "storetypecode_id")
  private StoreTypeCode storeTypeCode;

  public StoreTypeCodeTranslation(){
    // Do nothing
  }
}
```

StoreTypeCodeTranslation table acts as translation for StoreTypeCode.
In SQL, I would use the following to get StoreTypeCode for a certain language.

```sql
SELECT STC.id, STC.displaysort, STT.type1, STT.type2 
FROM storetypecode AS STC
LEFT JOIN storetypecodetranslation AS STT on STC.id = STT.storetypecode_id
WHERE STT.lang = 'en'
ORDER BY STC.displaysort ASC
```

How do I use JPARepository to get result as written in my SQL code above?  Also if there is no translated StoreTypeCode for language, it should return the result with 'isDefault=true'.

I am still new to JPARepository and trying to get most out of its library.  It would be greatly appreciated if someone could guide me where to start.

Thank you

UPDATE ------------------------
I have the following repository setup.

```java
public interface StoreTypeCodeRepository extends JpaRepository<StoreTypeCode, UUID> {

  @Query(
      value = "SELECT STC.id, STC.displaysort, STT.type1, STT.type2\n"
          + "FROM storetypecode AS STC\n"
          + "LEFT JOIN storetypecodetranslation AS STT on STC.id = STT.storetypecode_id\n"
          + "WHERE STT.lang = ?1\n"
          + "ORDER BY STC.displaysort ASC", nativeQuery = true)
  List<StoreTypeCodeResult> findByLanguage(String language);
}
```

And I created StoreTypeCodeResult as DTO class as below

```java
public class StoreTypeCodeResult {

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Type(type="pg-uuid")
  private UUID id;
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private Integer displaySort = 999;
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String type1;
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String type2;

  public StoreTypeCodeResult(){

  }

}
```

When I run the code, I get error saying  No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You write a method in your repository, you annotate it with `@Query`, and you pass the appropriate JPQL query (or even native query) as the value of this annotation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. I updated the question above. Am I doing something wrong here?